# Django does not save form model

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.8 and Python 2.7

`job_form.is_valid()` is `True`, but it does not save anything because Django can't detect the changed data. I attach a picture.

View code:[image]

Python 2.7 str has no attribute **iter**, only python 3+ but I can't upgrade it. 
why is not working Django 1.8 with Python 2.7?

```
job_form = JobEditForm(request.POST, instance=job)
    if job_form.is_valid():
        job_form.save()
        return HttpResponse(status=200)

    else: return HttpResponse(job_form.errors.as_json(), status=404)
```

Comment: Can you share your `JobEditForm`?

Comment: Django 1.8 [went out of Extended Support over a year ago](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/). I understand that some projects have to run on legacy platforms, but being stuck on this version is extremely bad for you with regard to security. I had to migrate a project on an even older version of Django to the 2.x branch last year, and while it was a pain, it's absolutely worth doing.